# How Run-Time error from File Handling code can be detected and removed?

Tags: c++, runtime-error

Q :Why is not this code working properly?

I have implemented file handling in C++ language.

I have created a complete file of the car. Through this code, we can store new data, delete old one, search a particular data about the car.The problem is that this code compiles successfully but during runtime, its execution stops and display an error message. I request kindly help me in removing runtime error from this code.

CODE:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

struct car
{
    char name[20];
    int  model;
    string color;
    int car_id;
    string size;
    float weight;
    int price;
};

void getdata(car&);         //function declaration
void showdata(car&);        //function declaration
void searchdata();          //function declaration
void deleterecord();        //function declaration
void modify();              //function declaration
void readdata();            //function declaration
void writedata();           //function declaration

int main()
{
    char ch;
    cout<<"\nEnter w to write record ";
    cout<<"\nEnter r to read record";
    cout<<"\nEnter m to modify record";
    cout<<"\nEnter s to search record";
    cout<<"\nEnter d to delete record";
    cout<<"\n\nEnter your choice :";
    cin>>ch;

    switch(ch)
    {
        case 'w':
        {
            writedata();
            break;
        }
        case 'r':
        {
            readdata();
            break;
        }
        case 's':
        {
            searchdata();
            break;
        }
        case 'd':
        {
            deleterecord();
            break;
        }

        case 'm':
        {
            modify();
            break;
        }
        default:
        {
            cout<<"\nWrong choice";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void getdata(car &ccc)
{
    cout<<"Please enter name of car :";
    cin>>ccc.name;
    cout<<"Please enter model number of car:";
    cin>>ccc.model;
    cout<<"Enter color of car:";
    cin>>ccc.color;
    cout<<"Enter id number of car:";
    cin>>ccc.car_id;
    cout<<"Enter size of car :";
    cin>>ccc.size;
    cout<<"Enter weight of a car :";
    cin>>ccc.weight;
    cout<<"Enter price of a car :";
    cin>>ccc.price;
}

void showdata(car &ccc)
{
    cout<<"\nName of car is :";
    puts(ccc.name);
    cout<<"\nModel number of car is :"<<ccc.model;
    cout<<"\nColor of car is :"<<ccc.color;
    cout<<"\nID number of car is :"<<ccc.car_id;
    cout<<"\nSize of car is :"<<ccc.size;
    cout<<"\nWeight of car is :"<<ccc.weight;
    cout<<"\nPrice of car is :"<<ccc.price;
}

void writedata()
{
    ofstream file;
    char ch='y';
    car ccc;
    file.open("carinformation.dat",ios::binary | ios::out | ios::app);
    while(ch=='y'|| ch=='Y')
    {
        getdata(ccc);
        file.write((char*)&ccc,sizeof(ccc));
        cout<<"\nDo you want to countine?";
        cin>>ch;
    }
    file.close();
}

void readdata()
{
    int count=0;
    ifstream file;
    car ccc;
    file.open("carinformation.dat",ios::binary | ios::in);
    if(!file)
    {
        cout<<"File not found";
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        file.read((char*)&ccc,sizeof(ccc));
        while(!file.eof())
        {
            showdata(ccc);
            file.read((char*)&ccc,sizeof(ccc));
            count++;
        }
        cout<<"Number of records are :"<<count;
    }
    file.close();
}

void searchdata()
{
    car ccc;
    ifstream file;
    char n_c[20];
    cout<<"Enter name of car :";
    cin>>n_c;
    file.open("carinformation.dat",ios::binary | ios::in);
    if(!file)
    {
        cout<<"File nnot found";
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        file.read((char*)&ccc, sizeof(ccc));
        while(!file.eof())
        {
            if(strcmp(n_c,ccc.name)==0)
            {
                showdata(ccc);

            }
            file.read((char*)&ccc, sizeof(ccc));
        }
    }
    file.close();
}

void modify()
{
    car ccc;
    fstream file;
    char n_c[20];
    file.open("carinformation.dat",ios::binary | ios::in | ios::out);
    cout<<"\nEnter name of car that should be searched:";
    cin>>n_c;
    if(!file)
    {
        cout<<"File not found";
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        file.read((char*)&ccc,sizeof(ccc));
        while(!file.eof())
        {
            if(strcmp(n_c,ccc.name)==0)
            {
                file.seekg(0, ios::cur);
                cout<<"Enter new record :\n";
                getdata(ccc);
                int i=file.tellg();
                int j=sizeof(ccc);
                int k=i-j;
                file.seekp(k);
                file.write((char*)&ccc, sizeof(ccc));
            }

        }
    }
    file.read((char*)&ccc, sizeof(ccc));
    file.close();
}
void deleterecord()
{
    int count=0;
    car ccc;
    int c_id;
    cout<<"Please enter car id :";
    cin>>c_id;
    ifstream file;
    file.open("carinformation.dat" ,ios::binary| ios::in);
    ofstream file2;
    file2.open("New carinformation.dat", ios::binary| ios::out);
    while(file.read((char*)&ccc,sizeof(ccc)))
    {
        if(ccc.car_id!=c_id)
        {
            file2.write((char*)&ccc ,sizeof(ccc));
            count++;
        }
    }
    cout<<"Number of records are :"<<count;
    file2.close();
    count=0;
    file2.open("New carinformation.dat", ios::binary| ios::in);
    file.read((char*)&ccc,sizeof(ccc));
    while(!file.eof())
    {
        count++;
        showdata(ccc);
        file.read((char*)&ccc,sizeof(ccc));
    }
    cout<<"Number of records are :"<<count;
    file.close();
    file2.close();
    remove("carinfomation.dat");
    rename("New carinformation.dat", "carinformation.dat");
    file.open("carinformation.dat", ios::binary  | ios::in);
    file.read((char*)&ccc, sizeof(ccc));
    while(!file.eof())
    {
        count++;
        showdata(ccc);
        file.read((char*)&ccc, sizeof(ccc));
    }
    cout<<"Number of records are :"<<count;
}
```

Comment: I recommend writing less between tests to avoid having hundreds of lines of code and no clue where the bug is. In this case you have a really big problem because there are a lot of bugs. Fixing one won't help much, and you might not even realize you fixed it.

Comment: This question needs to be rewritten to focus on the line of code that has the runtime error.  Simplify what code is shown to focus on the error (showing just enough to be pertinent) or better yet, develop a far simpler file of code that still has the error.   And always show the error message and what line it's on when asking such questions.

Comment: Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Comment: I know that minimal code is effective and good but as it is my final semester project so its length increased.

Comment: You shouldn't need to throw your whole program at us.  Narrow it down to just the part that isn't working, and make a [mcve] of just that bit.  If you're having trouble identifying the part that's at fault, it's time to learn some elementary debugging techniques.  When you say, *"its execution stops and display an error message"*, you need to be much more specific - are we supposed to guess the contents of the message (and guess what inputs you gave)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class `car` has `std::string` fields which hold pointers to heap-allocated memory. So saving it to file by writing raw bytes `file.write((char*)&ccc,sizeof(ccc));` is not going to work. And, what is more important, reading them later `file.read((char*)&ccc, sizeof(ccc));` will fill string objects with invalid pointer values. You need to store fields one by one and read them one by one carefully validating input data.

Comment: Search term for more information: serialization.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between "string" and "string.h". Delete two characters, ".h" and see if your code works.

```
<string.h> contains functions like strcpy, strlen for C style null-terminated strings.
<string> contains std::string, std::wstring plus other classes.
```

You need to initialize your struct, heres an example for your readdata(), look at the changes and figure out how to fix the rest of the program:

```
void readdata()
{
    int count=0;
    ifstream file;
    car *ccc = new car();
    file.open("carinformation.dat",ios::binary | ios::in);
    if(!file)
    {
        cout<<"File not found";
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        file.read((char*)ccc,sizeof(*ccc));
        while(!file.eof())
        {
            showdata(*ccc);
            file.read((char*)ccc,sizeof(*ccc));
            count++;
        }
        cout<<"Number of records are :"<<count;
    }
    file.close();
}
```

Comment: A good idea, but this wouldn't result in a runtime error.

Comment: Thanks @user4581301, I updated my answer.